# How much Omer-measure does an Omer-Sheaf (Leviticus 23:10) have or how much Omer [of flour or of grain] would it contain?

Tags: mincha-meal-offering

How much Omer-measure does an Omer-Sheaf ([Leviticus 23:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0323.htm#10)) have or how much Omer [of flour or of grain] would it contain?

> דַּבֵּ֞ר אֶל־בְּנֵ֤י יִשְׂרָאֵל֙ וְאָֽמַרְתָּ֣ אֲלֵהֶ֔ם כִּֽי־תָבֹ֣אוּ אֶל־הָאָ֗רֶץ אֲשֶׁ֤ר אֲנִי֙ נֹתֵ֣ן לָכֶ֔ם וּקְצַרְתֶּ֖ם אֶת־קְצִירָ֑הּ וַֽהֲבֵאתֶ֥ם אֶת־עֹ֛מֶר רֵאשִׁ֥ית קְצִֽירְכֶ֖ם אֶל־הַכֹּהֵֽן׃
>
> Speak unto the children of Israel, and say unto them: When ye are come into the land which I give unto you, and shall reap the harvest thereof, then ye shall bring the sheaf of the first-fruits of your harvest unto the priest.

Does the Omer-Sheaf (that is bundled in one bundle) approximately produce one Omer-Measure [of flour or of grain] (that is, a tenth part of an ephah)?

Whether yes or no, where in the Tanach or Talmud does it say so?

My question is NOT about how much an Omer is, but how much Omer [of flour or of grain] approximately does an Omer-Bundle (which some people call a "Wave-Offering") contain or could contain? (Does one Omer-Bundle generally produce one Omer of flour or one Omer of grain?)

I am trying to find out if there is a general amount given in the Tanach or Talmud, something like, perhaps:

"Each person's Omer-Bundle will produce approximately one Omer-Measure (of flour or of grain) to that person."

Answer (score 2):

The reaped barley indeed produced an *omer* of flour, or a little more. I guess, as experienced farmers and millers, they knew about how much to cut. [*M'nachos*, chapter 10 *mishna* 1](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Menachot.10.1), describes how much that was. [*Mishna* 4 there](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Menachot.10.4) says that there was some left over — I guess it's better to cut a little too much than to risk being understocked — and indicates that those leftovers were sold.

---

Incidentally, I don't know why you call it a sheaf or say that it was "bundled in one bundle". And you're mistaken to say "Each person's Omer-Bundle": there was one *omer* offering for the whole nation. But all that is beside the point of your question, which I think I've addressed adequately above.

Comment: My question was basically, how big of a sheaf is needed to get an omer? To make your adequate answer complete, perhaps you can find out from the rabbinic writings, the  circumference and height of a sheaf that "indeed produced an omer of flour". Thanks in advance.